# Video won't load on first try

Tags: javascript, aframe, virtual-reality

I´m using the asset management to load a .mp4 Clip (5 MB) and want to display it via A-Frame (1.0.4)

`a-video src="ID"`

Now the problem appears that it wont load on the first try.
I´m just getting a black plane.
After a reload of the page it appears.
That not a problem with only one clip...it won't work on multiple clips within the scene.

I´m using pace.min.js for preloading but that doesnt look like the problem.

Maybe someone here has some suggestions?

Regards
Pascal

Comment: Can you provide a full example? It's hard to guess what the problem is with such few details, sorry.

Comment: Hi Stéphane,
thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complicated to get the media autoplay on modern browsers, so it's better to add the a-video dynamically. As said in my comment, you can have a modal window or anything with a button to add the video to the scene and launch it. Here is a simple example on how to do it.

```
// This will create the tag and remove the button from the page when it's done.
document.getElementById("video-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var video = document.createElement("a-video");
        video.setAttribute("src", "#videoclip");
        video.setAttribute("width", "16");
        video.setAttribute("height", "9");
        video.setAttribute("rotation", "0 180 0");
        video.setAttribute("position", "-2 2 -4.15");
        video.addEventListener("loaded", function() {
            document.getElementById("videoclip").load();
            document.getElementById("videoclip").play();
        });
        document.querySelector("a-scene").appendChild(video);
        this.remove();
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="3D Model">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
   <body>
     <a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
<!--Assets -->
  <a-assets>
    <video id="videoclip" autoplay loop="true" src="assets/clip.mp4"></video>
     </a-assets>
  
<!--Camera Rig -->
    <a-entity movement-controls="speed: 0.2; constrainToNavMesh: true" position="0 4 20">

<!-- Camera -->
        <a-entity camera position="0 1.8 0"
                look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: false">
        </a-entity>
    </a-entity>
<!--Video -->
  <a-video src="#videoclip" width="2.15" height="1" rotation=" 0 180 0" position="-2 2 -4.15"></a-video>

    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Regards!

Comment: Ok, I found another hint. 
In Chrome it won't work as described. 
In Safari the first image of the Clip is visible but it won't play. 
n Firefox it works fine.

Any Idea to get it working on all of this three browsers?

Regards!

Comment: Ok, for now it looks like it isnt directly a loading issue....
With the snippet above I tried to reproduce the error by reloading the page again and again, but now even on the second page load it wont work. BUT...on first try...open the browser...video is black...click somewhere (not on the video, just somewhere) the clip plays on the next reload.

Comment: It looks like the browser is waiting for something. After removing   cursor="rayOrigin: mouse"   the click is not longer helpfull but it will load on the second reload

Comment: Some browsers (at least chrome for sure) don't allow media autoplay on page load and require user gesture. So yes it can be complicated. But you could for example add a modal in front of your panorama and trigger video play after a button press or something like that.